# Is there a possible way that I can put an anyshape inside the text fill color and move it around?

Tags: javascript, css

I've been thinking this kind of thing in the past few days. If I can do the text-fill-color inside the text. Like [this link](https://css-tricks.com/4-ways-to-animate-the-color-of-a-text-link-on-hover/).

What this is trying to do is to when you hover it... it will fill the text color with blue, but what I want to happen is like... I can put the any shape inside the text because I've seen some projects that looks like it. I have sample code here:

```js
let mouseCursor = document.querySelector('.cursor')

window.addEventListener("mousemove", cursor)

function cursor(e) {
  mouseCursor.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
  mouseCursor.style.left = e.pageX + "px"
} <
/script>
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text h1 {
  color: orange;
}

.text h2 {
  font-size: 125px;
  background: radial-gradient( red 20%, orange 60%, red 20%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  /* background-size:  100%;
    background-position: 50%; */
}

.cursor {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background: rgb(20, 192, 97);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: none;
  transition: all 0.5 ease;
  transition-property: background, transform;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="text">
  <h1> HELLO WORLD </h1>
  <h2> HELLO WORLD </h2>
</div>
```

As you see, inside there is like a circle inside, but it is just a circle for a gradient. But I want my mouse cursor or maybe I want to put a circle inside there without using gradient color inside the text. If it's possible, I need a slightest clue or something else. What should I do?